# In String.replace("\c","") what ASCII value is ""?

Tags: string

im just writing my own replace method for any weird characters and i used the ASCI value 0, null to replace unwanted characters, i was hoping for them to be 'deleted', but this doesnt work. A gap just appears in the string.

What exactly does String.Replace() do when removing a character for ""? Does it shift them all down and then 'delete' the final character or something?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable - you cannot change a string. You can only create a new string with the characters removed. If you replace a string with the empty string, you simply create a new string that does not contain the matched characters.